# Set custom titleLabel properties for multiple UIButtons

Tags: ios

I've got a custom button like:

```
UIButton *catBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
catBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 344, 427, 67);
catBtn1.titleLabel.font = categoryFont;
catBtn1.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
catBtn1.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(52, 21, 150, 15);
catBtn1.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Is there a quick way to set all these `titleLabel` properties for all my buttons without doing this for each button? I tried assigning an instance of `UILabel` to `catBtn1.titleLabel` but that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create method that sets these properties and call it for each of your buttons.

Comment: I set all these button properties in my viewDidLoad method. Could I write this method inside that method? Or where would I put it? Thx

Comment: Yes, `viewDidLoad` is ok for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create method for button like this...

```
-(UIButton *) customBtn:(NSString *)btntxt:(CGFloat)btnx:(CGFloat)btny:(CGFloat)btnwidth
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[btn setTitle:btntxt forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.titleLabel.text = btntxt;
    btn.titleLabel.font = categoryFont;
    btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    btn.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(52, 21, 150, 15);
    btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(btnx, btny, btnwidth, 40)];
    return btn;
}
```

and you can call it like this any number of time when you need it

```
[YOURVIEW_OBJECT addSubview:[self customBtn:@"Samanmalliset" : 165:20 :115]];
```